# AVG with GROUP BY clause inside HAVING clause

Tags: sql, oracle

> Write a query to display the manufacturer and the number of models the
> company manufactures, if and only if the average warranty of the
> manufacturer is more than 3 years. Give an alias for the count as
> "TOTAL_COUNT". (Hint: Use Mobile_Master to table to retrieve records)
> **Do it in oracle sql**

```
select MANUFACTURER, count(IME_NO) AS 
TOTAL_COUNT
from MOBILE_MASTER
where WARRANTY_IN_YEARS>3
group BY MANUFACTURER;
```

This is the query that I have written but

***PROGRAM OUPUT***

```
MANUFACTURER TOTAL_COUNT
------------ -----------
Samsung           1
Nokia             1
```

***Expected Output***

```
MANUFACTURER TOTAL_COUNT
------------ -----------
Samsung           3
```

```
IME_NO     MODEL_NAME       MANUFACTURER         DATE_OF_MANUF WARRANTY_IN_YEARS     PRICE DISTRIBUTOR_ID SPEC_NO
---------- ---------- ----------
SA100010   SamsungS2        Samsung          12-APR-08             4
     25000 SA110      SP1
SA100020   SamsungS3        Samsung          02-MAR-10             3
     13000 SA110      SP2
SA100030   SamsungACE       Samsung          25-DEC-09             3
     15000 SA111      SP3
NO100010   NokiaAsha        Nokia            18-SEP-11             2
      6500 NO111      SP4
NO100020   NokiaLumiaB2     Nokia            15-OCT-07             2
     22000 NO110      SP3
NO100030   NokiaLumiaC2     Nokia            25-NOV-09             5
     14000 NO111      SP4
```

[image: SQL Schema]

Comment: Why do you expect "3" for samsung as output ? It as 3,3 and 4 years warranty. Of those 3 values only 4 is "more than 3". If you want to included 3 in your results, change your operator

Comment: I want to Write a query to display the manufacturer and the number of models the company manufactures, if and only if the average warranty of the manufacturer is more than 3 years.

Comment: You are just repeating what is in the question... did you read my remark ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having `where WARRANTY_IN_YEARS>3`, your question states

> ...only if the average warranty of the manufacturer is more than 3 years

The key word is AVERAGE.

To filter based on an aggregate function, you will need to use the filter in your `HAVING` clause and not your `WHERE` clause like this:

```sql
  SELECT MANUFACTURER, COUNT (IME_NO) AS TOTAL_COUNT
    FROM mobile_master
GROUP BY manufacturer
  HAVING AVG (WARRANTY_IN_YEARS) > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT manufacturer ,COUNT(manufacturer) AS TOTAL_COUNT 
from mobile_master 
GROUP BY manufacturer 
having AVG(warranty_in_years)>3 ;
```

Comment: Please explain your code (even code comments are helpful).